# My maternal 4th-great grandmother, born in 1787, had a Jewish maiden name, Zagel, and lived in Eastern Europe. Am I, therefore, Jewish?

Tags: genealogy, judaism

My maternal 4th-great grandmother, born in 1787, had a Jewish maiden name, Zagel, and lived in Eastern Europe. Am I, therefore, Jewish?

I was raised in the Roman Catholic religion, yet, since I was 8 years old, I have had an affinity for the Jewish people, their rich culture; minor-keyed liturgical music, inexplicably so.  This attraction and fascination has only grown over the years.  I found that on my father's side, I am of Sephardic heritage.

I am searching for more recent, contemporary ancestral connections to complete this genealogical mosaic.

Thank you so much.

Raegan

Comment: How do you know Zagel is a Jewish maiden name?

Comment: I don't know definitively.  However, in researching the name, its etymology and the given names of many such people with that surname, it leans substantively in that direction (Jewish).

Comment: You've been disconnected from Judaism for so long, unless you found definite proof that this maternal great-grandmother was Jewish, and that you are descended only from her female descendants afterwards, you would need to undergo conversion. Some authorities might require a conversion even if you found proof.